# Calculating RSI for new elements optimization

Tags: c#

The following formula would calculate RSI for all prices. Whenever I add a new price to the array, it would have to recalculate the RSI for the entire array/all prices. Is there a way I can calculate the RSI for the new price without having to recalculate the entire thing? I want to do that because when I'm calculating this for every new candle and it has to be executed for the least possible time. If it's not possible, can you please suggest me a way to optimize it, so it executes as fast as possible. Right now, it's not so fast.

```
decimal[] prices = ...
Calculate(prices, 14);
```

```
public decimal[] Calculate(decimal[] price, int period)
{
    var rsi = new decimal[price.Length];

    decimal gain = 0m;
    decimal loss = 0m;

    rsi[0] = 0m;

    for (int i = 1; i <= period; ++i)
    {
        var diff = price[i] - price[i - 1];
        if (diff >= 0)
        {
            gain += diff;
        }
        else
        {
            loss -= diff;
        }
    }

    decimal avrg = gain / period;
    decimal avrl = loss / period;
    decimal rs = gain / loss;
    rsi[period] = 100m - (100m / (1m + rs));

    for (int i = period + 1; i < price.Length; ++i)
    {
        var diff = price[i] - price[i - 1];

        if (diff >= 0)
        {
            avrg = ((avrg * (period - 1)) + diff) / period;
            avrl = (avrl * (period - 1)) / period;
        }
        else
        {
            avrl = ((avrl * (period - 1)) - diff) / period;
            avrg = (avrg * (period - 1)) / period;
        }

        rs = avrg / avrl;

        rsi[i] = 100m - (100m / (1m + rs));
    }

    return rsi;
}
```

Comment: If you keeps the number of items and the sum of the items then adding one more you do not have to calculate a sum.  The new sum is old sum + new value.  Then average is new sum / N + 1.

Comment: @jdweng, would you like to type that as an answer? Also, all I have is the `decimal[] price` containing all prices. But I can save the `gain` and `loss`